# What is `uvw` property of QPickTriangleEvent class

Tags: qt, qt3d

QPickTriangleEvent class has a [uvw](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qpicktriangleevent.html#uvw) property. What is it? Is `uvw` the normal vector of the triangle?

---

I log the QPickTriangleEvent properties:

```cpp
Qt3DRender::QPickTriangleEvent *eventTri = static_cast<Qt3DRender::QPickTriangleEvent *>(event);
qDebug() << "Triangle Index: " << eventTri->triangleIndex();
qDebug() << "Triangle Vertex 1: " << eventTri->vertex1Index();
qDebug() << "Triangle Vertex 2: " << eventTri->vertex2Index();
qDebug() << "Triangle Vertex 3: " << eventTri->vertex3Index();
qDebug() << "Triangle UVW: " << eventTri->uvw();
```

The output:

```
Triangle Index:  79540
Triangle Vertex 1:  238620
Triangle Vertex 2:  238621
Triangle Vertex 3:  238622
Triangle UVW:  QVector3D(0.0390438, 0.151772, 0.809184)
```

Even with examining the output I cannot figure `uvw` out. Is it the normal vector of the triangle?

---

I'm examining these source codes to figure out what `uvw` is:

[triangleboundingvolume_p.h](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.12/src/render/backend/triangleboundingvolume_p.h)

[triangleboundingvolume.cpp](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.12/src/render/backend/triangleboundingvolume.cpp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In source code [triangleboundingvolume.cpp](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/5.12/src/render/backend/triangleboundingvolume.cpp) it is commented:

```cpp
// RealTime Collision Detection page 192
bool intersectsSegmentTriangle(const RayCasting::QRay3D &ray, ...
```

Page 193 of [the book](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9781558607323/real-time-collision-detection) comments

> ... also returns the barycentric coordinates (u,v,w) of the intersection point s, ...

and page 194

> ... Segment intersects tri at distance t in position s (s = u*A + v*B + w*C) ...